# An exe file has installed but not opening

Tags: installation, windows-installation, repair-install

I have installed LabVIEW 7.1  software on windows 10 platform .The installation window showed that the installation has completed successfully.But when I tried to open its exe it is not opening and also does not pops any erroneous message.Most of my friends installed and successfully using the software (in same platform) that has been taken from same source.

I have tried compatability testing, repairing, modifing and also reinstalling the software.Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Can you use the newer version of this product?  The newest works on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

[LabVIEW 7.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW)
dates from 2004, when Windows was version Windows XP and even Windows 7 did not
yet exist.

If you insist on running it, you may try to right-click the executable of LabVIEW 7.1,
choose Properties, Compatibility tab, check
"Run this program in compatibility mode for:", select
"Windows XP (Service Pack 3)" and click OK.

But you would certainly get better results in Windows 10 by installing the
[latest LabVIEW version](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/software-products/download.labview.html#329483).